# Crear nueva variable y etiquetar según la salida de operaciones condicionales en R

Tags: r

Dispongo de un dataframe que es similar a [este.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7994feit6bly3n/datos.csv?dl=0)

Me gustaría crear una nueva columna denominada "Etiqueta" que contenga una etiqueta según el tipo de vector existente en la variable `datos$Population signals`.

En pseudocódigo, siendo `i` cada uno de los vectores que encontramos en la columna `datos$Population signals`:

```
for i in Population signals:
    if i contiene 1 valor >= 9:
        if valor está en las 2 primeras o dos últimas posiciones:
             print E en la columna "Etiqueta"
        else:
             print M en la columna "Etiqueta"
    else if i contiene 2 valores >= 4:
             print P en la columnna "Etiqueta"
    else if i contiene 3 o más valores > 2:
             print D en la columna "Etiqueta"
    else:
             print I en la columna "Etiqueta"
```

¿Cómo se hace algo así en R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una solución no exactamente usando una función for si no apply que es similar pero aplica una función sobre una columna, fila , en cada elemento por lo que se me hizo adecuado para el problema que planteabas , te comparto la solución

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#Leemos la información
base<-read.csv("C:/Users/rall8/Desktop/Stack/datos.csv")

#Generamos una lista con los valores en los corchetes es decir sacamos los valores de los corchetes y los convertimos a un data.frame
numeros<-data.frame(str_extract_all(base$Population.signals,"\\d+",simplify=TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
2   4  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  4   0
3   0  0  2  0  0  1  1  3  1   2
4   0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0   0
5   0  1  0  0  1  2  1  2  2   1
6   1  0  1  0  0  2  0  4  1   1
7   2  0  0  0  1  2  0  2  1   2
8   2  1  0  0  0  2  0  3  0   2
9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0   0
10  0  1  0  0  0  4  0  1  0   4
11  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  3  0   2
12  0  0  1  0  0  3  0  2  0   4
13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0   8
14  0  2  0  1  0  1  0  2  0   4
15  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   4
16  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   9
17  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   4
18  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   9
```

En el siguiente paso le cambie el nombre a la columna y ya comienza lo divertido que es la tipificación

```
#Cambiamos los valores vacios para NA
names(numeros)<-paste("columna",seq(1:10),sep="_")

#Creamos una columna donde agregaremos las etiquetas
numero_limpio[["Etiqueta"]]<-""

#Convertimos los valores a numericos
numeros_l<-map_df(numeros,as.numeric)


 numeros_l[["Estatus"]]<-apply(numeros_l,1,function(x){
                    if((sum(x>=9)==1) & (sum(x[1:2]>=9)==1 | sum(x[c(ncol(numeros_l):ncol(numeros_l)-1)]>=9)==1)){print("E")
  
                    }else if((sum(x>=9)==1)){print("M")
    
                    }else if((sum(x>=4)==2)){print("P")

                    }else if((sum(x>2)==3)){print("D")
  
                    }else{print("I")}})
```

## A tibble: 18 x 11

```
    columna_1 columna_2 columna_3 columna_4 columna_5 columna_6 columna_7 columna_8 columna_9 columna_10 Estatus
   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  
     1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1          1 I      
     2         4         0         0         0         2         0         0         0         4          0 P      
     3         0         0         2         0         0         1         1         3         1          2 I      
     4         0         0         0         0         9         0         0         0         0          0 M      
     5         0         1         0         0         1         2         1         2         2          1 I      
     6         1         0         1         0         0         2         0         4         1          1 I      
     7         2         0         0         0         1         2         0         2         1          2 I      
     8         2         1         0         0         0         2         0         3         0          2 I      
     9         0         0         0         0         0         0         0        10         0          0 M      
    10         0         1         0         0         0         4         0         1         0          4 P      
    11         1         1         1         0         1         1         0         3         0          2 I      
    12         0         0         1         0         0         3         0         2         0          4 I      
    13         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         2         0          8 I      
    14         0         2         0         1         0         1         0         2         0          4 I      
    15         0         6         0         0         0         0         0         0         0          4 P      
    16         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0          9 M      
    17         0         6         0         0         0         0         0         0         0          4 P      
    18         0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0          9 M
```

Al final solo unimos la información con la base original y ya queda todo listo

```
final<-cbind(base,numeros_l[,11])  


     Generation        Condition Inst_power              Population.signals Estatus
 1           1 Homogeneity PR 0        0.0  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]       I
 2           1 Homogeneity PR 0        0.5  [4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]       P
 3           1 Homogeneity PR 0        1.0  [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2]       I
 4           2 Homogeneity PR 0        0.0  [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]       M
 5           2 Homogeneity PR 0        0.5  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]       I
 6           2 Homogeneity PR 0        1.0  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1]       I
 7           1 Homogeneity PR W        0.0  [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2]       I
 8           1 Homogeneity PR W        0.5  [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2]       I
 9           1 Homogeneity PR W        1.0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]       M
 10          2 Homogeneity PR W        0.0  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 4]       P
 11          2 Homogeneity PR W        0.5  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2]       I
 12          2 Homogeneity PR W        1.0  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 4]       I
 13          1 Homogeneity PR R        0.0  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8]       I
 14          1 Homogeneity PR R        0.5  [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4]       I
 15          1 Homogeneity PR R        1.0  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]       P
 16          2 Homogeneity PR R        0.0  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]       M
 17          2 Homogeneity PR R        0.5  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]       P
 18          2 Homogeneity PR R        1.0  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]       M
```